# Bad configuration option: pubkeyacceptedalgorithms

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat

I want to connect to Red Hat Linux server, but I the the error `Bad configuration option: pubkeyacceptedalgorithms`

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot 2]

when I use putty to connect to the server I get the error `Network error: connection refused`

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please  when posting console output / settings format it as "`code`" using [Markdown](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. Also use copy-paste and avoid posting screenshots of text. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions.

Answer (score 8):

The `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` option in config file should read as below:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-dss
```

Equal sign `=` can be used on command line with `-o` option but it is not allowed in config file.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the error in the configuration file, then sshd will be able to start and you'll be able to log in with PuTTY - `man sshd_config` should show what values are acceptable for `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` but both the `=` sign  as you current wild-card `*ssh-dss` appear incorrect.

That setting should look something like:

```
 PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512
```

or

```
 PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com
```